# ROLLBACK DB access after calling PA30 transaction from code

Tags: abap, rollback

We make change in infotype record using the following call:

```
CALL TRANSACTION 'PA30' USING         gt_bdcdata
                        OPTIONS FROM  ls_ctu_params
                        MESSAGES INTO et_mess.
```

Where `gt_bdecdata` contains:

[image: gt_bdecdata]

And `ls_ctu_params` contains:

[image: ls_ctu_params]

The reason to use `CALL TRANSACTION` and not a function module such as `HR_INFOTYPE_OPERAION` is the existence of old-fashioned dynamic actions in `t588z` table, which would be triggered only with `CALL TRANSACTION`.

After that call, we have further DB access, which when failed, should lead to a general rollback, which need to affect the mentioned call.

We didn't realize how to rollback DB state back into what was before `CALL TRANSACTION` call.

We tried to:

1. Use a `ROLLBACK WORK` statement.
2. Make a call to `BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK` `FM`.
3. Turn on `RACOMMIT` flag in `ls_ctu_params` strcuture.

None made the rollback.

Comment: There are plenty of `Commit Work` statements in the program SAPMP50A (TA PA30). I would put breakpoints on them and check if you pass one while debugging. Have you tried that? It seems to me that the LUW with finishes before you're able to check it

Comment: Thanks @stego I already tried to skip them all. then made options 1,2,3 without success.

Comment: `UPMODE = 'K'` !? Hopefully any invalid value is [interpreted as 'A' (asynchronous)](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapcall_transaction_using.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@).

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi. Keyboard neighbors... Edited.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to rollback the completed call.
The transaction called is loaded in a separate internal session and another [LUW](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abensap_luw.htm), so once processed the database changes PA30 are commited and cannot be undone.

You should try to go back to using a FM/BAPI with something like a BADI implementation to handle the actions giving you trouble or alternatively change the data back to its initial state by repeating the transaction.

Comment: Generally speaking (I don't know what `PA30` does), if the transaction did some updates but didn't do a `COMMIT WORK`, then adding a `ROLLBACK WORK` after CALL TRANSACTION` would cancel the updates. Of course, that would be considered a flaw in any code which does an update but not a COMMIT WORK (or a database commit).

Comment: Hey @SandraRossi. I put statement breakpoint and skipped any single `COMMIT WORK`, and made a `ROLLBACK WORK` after `CALL TRANSACTION`, and the data wasn't roll-backed.

Comment: @Dorad Thanks. I forgot to say, and that was important because here the discussion is about batch input (simulation of screens): there's an implicit database commit after every screen display (or simulation). So, if the updates are done directly (without an update task) make sure that the skipped COMMIT WORK happen only after last BDCDATA screen. Eventually, it may require that the transaction leaves unfinished with a 1001 return code and the message `s344(00)` ("No batch input data for dynpro & &"). **But** skipping `COMMIT WORK` is not recommended because it's a modification of the standard.